# What are these SMD components with 3 leads?

Tags: surface-mount, component-selection, vacuum-fluorescent

[image]

[image]

Full resolution [link is here](https://photos.app.goo.gl/BgYGciWahvHFCP2VA)

I am trying to repair a vacuum fluorescent display module by Futaba model code is M402SD07GS. It is seen that there is no energy on the display and Vcc and GND legs are short-circuited at "C1162" grid/anode driver.

When I look at the circuit to understand where the short circuit is, I am encountered these 3-lead components with very short codes on them.

Since I do not know what these components are, I cannot continue to understand where the short circuit is. I can not order because I do not know the product codes

When I look closely, the following is written on the components.

```
L G for Q1 
332 for ZD1
D3  for D2
D3  for D3
113 for ZD2
```

Is there a way to figure out what this 3-legged component is?

Comment: Q is probably for a BJT (M would be for a MOSFET normally), ZD is zener diode and D is a regular diode.

Comment: I can't tell you what the exact part numbers are for all of these, but it might help your search to know that that form factor is called a SOT-23 package.

Comment: Having watched a few of Loius Rossman's YouTube videos, I suggest that you check the capacitors for short circuits first. They will be easier to find replacements for.

Comment: @AndrewMorton can you suggest me a video?

Comment: @mehmet My memory is not good enough to remember which components were faulty in which videos. My idea was that if the faulty component is a capacitor, then you will not need to try to find out what the hard-to-identify components are.

Answer (score 2):

The package is called "SOT-23" ([small outline transistor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small-outline_transistor)), and it is used for all kinds of small-signal semiconductor devices, including BJTs, MOSFETs and diodes of all types (single and dual).

Since they are very tiny, only a small amount of information can be printed on them for identification. These tend to be manufacturer-specific strings of letters and digits, and tracing them back to a specific device is somewhat of a black art. There are websites that can help with this.

As Andy says, the reference designator on the board can offer some general clues about where to look.

- D generally denotes a diode (or pair of diodes)
- ZD would be a zener diode specifically
- Q generally denotes a transistor (could be BJT or MOSFET)
- M would generally be specifically a MOSFET
- U might be some kind of integrated circut, such as a voltage reference or low-power regulator